# Binding to a property of an object in XAML not working

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I am new to WPF and data binding. So I am trying some things but now encountered a problem that defies everything I find in reference material.

I have a test program with a string TestString1 that is bound to the Text property of a TextBox tbTest1, that works.

And I have an object TestString2 from ClassTestString2 that contains one property Str. And I want to bind Str to the Text property of a TextBox tbTest2. So I use Text="{Binding Path=TestString2.Str}". According to all documentation you can drill down to a property of an object with the normal C# syntax. But it simply doesn't bind, it doesn't show when starting the program and also making changes in tbTest2 are not reflected in TestString2.Str.

When I use this.DataContext = TestString2; and Text="{Binding Path=Str}", it works but than TestString1 is not bound anymore.

I have the following simple piece of XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBindingStringOnly.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfBindingStringOnly"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox 
            x:Name="tbTest1" 
            Text="{Binding Path=TestString1}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" 
            Margin="124,47,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
        <TextBox 
            x:Name="tbTest2" 
            Text="{Binding Path=TestString2.Str}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" 
            Margin="124,126,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And C# code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using static WpfBindingStringOnly.MainWindow;

namespace WpfBindingStringOnly
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public string TestString1 { get; set; }

        public class ClassTestString2
        {
            public string Str { get; set; }

            public ClassTestString2(string s)
            {
                Str = s;
            }
        }

        public ClassTestString2 TestString2;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            TestString1 = "Hello1";
            TestString2 = new("Hello2");

            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any sort of binding warning message in your output window?  Those can be very helpful in diagnosing binding errors.   Just to be sure, try this longer, explicit binding.  Give your Windows a n x:Name attibute value.  For example, give it the attribute value `x:Name="Root"`.  The, change your binding to `Text="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=TestString2.Str}"`  See if that has any effect.  If it does, you just had a binding error.

Comment: And yes, once a binding is properly set up with source and path, it is perfectly valid to drill down into a property with C# "dot" syntax

Comment: @Joe: yes, I did get an error message (_40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TestString2' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=TestString2.Str; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='tbTest2'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')_) in the output window but like a lot of error messages, only when you solved the problem, you understand the message.
I even tried extended diagnostics from [wpf-tutorial](https://wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/) but same problem there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings work on properties, not fields.

Change your `TestString2` member from

```cs
public ClassTestString2 TestString2; // This is a field.
```

to

```cs
public ClassTestString2 TestString2 { get; set; } // This is a property.
```

Comment: Wouw, yes, that solved the problem. I did know that you can only bind to properties, but didn't realize that TestString2 was considered a field (stupid of me). Thanks!!!

Comment: Haha.  If it makes you feel any better, I've been doing WPF for years and my eyes glossed right over that.  I should have known better.